# How to pass a parameter to a script in \href?

Tags: hyperref

This is a borderline question, but the essential point concerns the usage of the construct

```latex
\href{run:....}{....}
```

from the \hyperref package, which is poorly documented, so here it is. I would like to launch a compiled AppleScript script (I'm on a Mac) and it works perfectly. The line

```latex
\href{run:beep.app}{prova}
```

creates a clickable link 'prova' in the pdf, and clicking on it launches the script beep.app. I understand that 'run:' is more or less equivalent to 'file:', that is to say, my pdf viewer is simply trying to open the file beep.app as if I were double clicking on it (right?). Since my system defaults to launching the script when clicked on, the result is that the script is executed.

Now to my question: I would like to pass an argument (a string) to the script. How can I do this? is there any technique allowing to do this? If I were to launch the script from the command line, the syntax would be "beep.app arg", but of course the following command fails miserably, as it is obvious:

```latex
\href{run:beep.app arg}{prova}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what arguments could be used there, but the `run:` is implemented in `hyperref.sty` as `\def\@hyper@launch run:#1\\#2#3{% filename, anchor text, linkname`. So, it appears that your "filename" is your "script", and you can still pass "anchor text" and "linkname" to your script (separated by ``\\``, if I understand correctly). Something like `\href{run:beep.app\\{<anchor>}{<linkname>}{prova}` would be my guess (but it's just a guess).

Comment: I don't think that pdf support this.

Comment: Listen to Ulrike, not me. :-)

Comment: Small correction on my guess:  `\href{run:beep.app\\{<anchor>}{<linkname>}}{prova}`

Comment: Not tested: you could, perhaps, put the whole command line in a shell script, and call this one in `\href`.

Comment: gusbrs's suggestion does not work. as to AlexG's suggestion, I still would not know how to pass the argument to the shell script, without hard coding it into the script